# Missing and Additional values in 2 list

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
list1 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6']
list2 = ['4','5','6','7','8']
```

Now I want to find missing and additional value in list2.

The output should be:

```
Missing value = 1,2,3
Additional Value = 7,8
```

Comment: Does the order matter?  Does multiplicity matter (how many `'2'`s there are, i.e. could you want `Missing value = 1,2,2,3`)?

Comment: Yes I want missing values too in list2

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [python sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) to list the  differences:

```
set(list1).difference(list2)
set(list2).difference(list1)
```

Result:

```
>>> print 'Missing values =', ','.join(set(list1).difference(list2))
Missing values = 1,3,2
>>> print 'Additional values =', ','.join(set(list2).difference(list1))
Additional values = 7,8
```

If order matters, then you still need to use sets:

```
set1, set2 = set(list1), set(list2)
[i for i in list1 if i not in set2]
[i for i in list2 if i not in set1]
```

Result:

```
>>> print 'Missing values =', ','.join([i for i in list1 if i not in set2])
Missing values = 1,2,3
>>> print 'Missing values =', ','.join([i for i in list2 if i not in set1])
Additional values = 7,8
```